# Importing and exporting data from a database to another using SyBase is taking a long time

Tags: import, export, sybase, sybase-sql-anywhere

In order to update a database(Sybase Adaptive Server Anywhere 8) I'm taking all the data from one database on clients computer and using

```
SELECT * FROM tabelName OUTPUT TO 'C:\path' FORMAT ASCII DELIMITED BY ';';
```

Then I'm using those files to update another database that's connected to a server by making temporary tables, checking if anything is missing and then dropping the temporary table.

```
INPUT INTO tempTable FROM 'C:\path' FORMAT ASCII DELIMITED BY ';';

INSERT INTO mainTable 
SELECT * 
FROM tempTable 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM mainTable);

DROP TABLE tempTable;
```

So I am wondering if there is a better way to do this since two tables are taking a very long time to export and import the data(they do have a ton of columns and data though but still and by ton of data I mean ~100 columns and ~100,000 worth of rows). It's especially weird since another table with similar amount of data goes by very quickly(although it does have less columns). The two tables that are taking a while are reading data ~1000 per sec while others are much faster.

Each client has the database.db file on their laptop. They get some data and need to submit it but have no connection, so they use their own .db file and update the one on the server later.

Getting the SQL definitions might be hard since tables were made a while back and I have no clue how to get them. The destination database is the database that holds all the data while source ones are the ones that are not connected and can be used offline if needed.

Some recommendations, tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you consider using dbunload with -an flag? Should be the fastes way for upgrading between pre ASA10 to post ASA10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without getting too involved in specific details on the language required to do this in Sybase SQL Anywhere 8, which is now more than 15 years old, I'd recommend something like the following:

- create a table on the laptop database that contains a column which uniquely identifies rows that have already been exported to the main database.
- the export function would do something like the following:

  ```
  SELECT * 
  FROM tableName 
  WHERE tableName.KeyColumn NOT IN (
      SELECT KeyColumn 
      FROM PreviouslyExportedTable
      ) 
  OUTPUT TO 'C:\path' FORMAT ASCII DELIMITED BY ';';
  ```
- Exporter then inserts rows into the `PreviouslyExportedTable` that don't already exist.  Next time the exporter runs, it will only export new rows that weren't already exported.  The insert code might look like:

  ```
  INSERT INTO PreviouslyExportedTable
  SELECT KeyColumn
  FROM TableName
  WHERE KeyColumn NOT IN (
      SELECT KeyColumn 
      FROM PreviouslyExportedTable
      );
  ```

This should drastically reduce the number of rows that need to be exported and imported each time.  It is uncertain to me if SQL Anywhere 8 supports using `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clauses instead of `WHERE NOT IN`; the `NOT EXISTS` variant *might* be faster, if it works.

Comment: NOT EXISTS (sub query) was supported in ASA 8